# How to deal with small edits that don't fix the many problems with a post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Take the following question:

[image]

The following are what I can see wrong with the question:

- The title
- The description
- The code indentation
- The tags (Although the editor removed [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), I'd argue that [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) should be removed too)

Now, I could improve the suggested edit, but would the editor actually know that they've done something "wrong"?

I could reject the edit, but I didn't feel it the correct course of action because it wasn't an incorrect edit, it had removed a tag which had nothing to do with a question.

In this scenario how would I go about informing the user about their edit and the issue with it?

Comment: I would reject. Removing that tag was the least meaningful improvement for that question. Suggested edits should at least _try_ to be comprehensive.

Comment: I tend to reject tag-only edits, unless they're essential to the post, e.g. tagging a question with the programming language used. People should not put edits removing a single tag in the queue.

Answer (score 15):

If you have the spare time and if the question is salvageable, in my opinion the best course of action would be to **reject and edit**. The reason for this is three-fold:

- Instantly rejects this edit proposal without the need for a second opinion.
- Allows you to instantly edit the question into a much better quality than the suggestion proposed.
- Gives the original edit proposer an idea of what constitutes a "good" edit on Stack Overflow

In your question you state several areas that you believe are wrong with the question in its current form, but are not addressed in the proposed edit. You have more than 2k reputation, therefore you have the power to take matters into your own hands. Likewise, you also have the power to correct minor faults in questions and answers without sending these trivial edits to the review queue, make the most of that ability.

The caveat to this, if you *weren't* sure how to improve the question despite the proposed edit being "bad" or destructive, then a simple **reject** is acceptable.